# 1 errors occurred during unsubscription

Tags: angular, typescript

When I call one request every second I get this error:

> core.js:5967 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
>
> at LoadingBackdropService.hide (loading-backdrop.service.ts:18)
>
> at TapSubscriber._tapNext (payment.component.ts:57)
>
> at TapSubscriber._next (tap.js:40)
>
> at TapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>
> at SwitchMapSubscriber.notifyNext (switchMap.js:70)
>
> at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:11)
>
> at InnerSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>
> at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
>
> at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
>
> at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)

How can the error be corrected?

ts:

```typescript
      ngUnsubscribe: Subscription;
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.load();
      }
    
      load() {
        this.loadingBackdrop.show();
        this.ngUnsubscribe = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
          switchMap(() => this._object.get(this.card.card_id)
            .pipe(finalize(() => this.loadingBackdrop.hide())))
        ).subscribe(data => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data));
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.ngUnsubscribe !== undefined) {
          this.ngUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
        }
      }
```

loading-backdrop.service.ts:

```
  show() {
    const backdropWrapperElement = this.createLoadingBackdropTemplate();
    const bodyElement = document.querySelector('body');
    bodyElement.appendChild(backdropWrapperElement);
  }

  hide() {
    const backdropWrapperElement = document.querySelector('#loadingBackdrop');
    backdropWrapperElement.remove();
  }

  private createLoadingBackdropTemplate(): HTMLDivElement {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.setAttribute('id', 'loadingBackdrop');
    element.setAttribute('style', `
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 999;
    `);
    element.innerHTML = `
      <div class="backdrop"></div>
      <div class="spinner">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    `;
    return element;
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide more code or possible a stackblitz workable demo? ? I think the issue can be in the `loadingBackdrop` but have no wayo to check that out

Comment: the problem is that the element does not have the `loadingBackdrop` ID isn't it? can you also share the `createLoadingBackdropTemplate()` function?

Comment: Please provide `createLoadingBackdropTemplate()` (or rather the respective dom element that is created). `document.querySelector` does not find what you want (possibly missing the id as Dario mentioned).

Comment: When you inspect the dom in the browser, does the element actually exist?

Comment: Gunnar's right, I think that 100% the issue is simply that `document.querySelector` returns `null` you need to makes sure that the element exists and that it's been given the correct id

Comment: @DarioPiotrowicz But `document.querySelector` it doesn't return to me `null`

Comment: it doesn't??? But that's what the error message is implying!!! :(
Could you maybe create a workable demo on https://stackblitz.com/ so that we can actually inspect the code and see why it's failing?

Comment: Or if your code is in a repo or anything like that, if you allow us to play around with it ourselves that would be of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use the `takeUntil` operator

```typescript
import { Subject } from 'rxjs'
import { takeUntil, tap } from 'rxjs/operators'
  destroyed$ = new Subject();
  ngOnInit() {
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    this.loadingBackdrop.show();
    timer(0, 1000).pipe(
      switchMap(() => this._object.get(this.card.card_id)),
      tap(() => this.loadingBackdrop.hide()),
      takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
    ).subscribe(data => this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroyed$.next()
  }
```

The idea is that as long as `destroyed$` is not triggered, then the `Observable` stream will be active but angular will automatically unsubscribe from the Observable once `destroyed$` Observable is not null

I have also changed `finalize` to `tap`. finalize will execute once the stream completes but tap will tap into the observable stream

Comment: I still have a mistake

Comment: Please check now, I have made a slight change on the code

Comment: If done this way, it does not execute `finalize (() => this.loadingBackdrop.hide())`

Comment: This is not related to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the error seems from this line

```
.pipe(finalize(() => this.loadingBackdrop.hide())))
```

and specifically from inside the `hide` method, make sure the loadingBackdrop object is correctly instantiated .

Answer (score -1):

try changing it to this:

```
if (this.ngUnsubscribe !== undefined && this.ngUnsubscribe !== null) {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: What for? Look at my full request as it looks in `load()`

Comment: You can't do .pipe when there's a semicolon...if you chain calls semicolons will break it.

Comment: It is like writing this: `this.loadingBackdrop;.show()`...will also not work, because there is a semicolon. A semicolon always ends the line / command, if you want to keep accessing stuff from the previous line you'll have to remove the semicolons

Comment: Also...there are no semicolons in the load function...that's why it works but the other one doesn't

Comment: You do not understand me. I took this part from the load function

Comment: Just try what I said...it will not throw an error

Comment: If you want to call .pipe on this.loadingBackdrop.show() you'll have to remove the semicolon

Comment: If you want to call .pipe on something else, you'll have to say `someOtherVariable`.pipe....

Comment: Oh...I got it now...sorry.